# UIToolbaritems showing very close to status bar icons then at the bottom of the UIToolbar in ios7

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

Using **UIToolbarDelegate** in the view controller and also tried using **UIBarPositioningDelegate** in the view controller and also using this method in the same view controller

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar

{
    return UIBarPositionBottom;
}
```

but after using all this still toolbar items showing very close to status bar icons.

Not using Interface builder but toolbar items frame position added programmatically.

Any ideas please how to show toolbar items at the bottom of the toolbar.

Thanks